# What does parameter in Array toString do?

Tags: javascript

I saw a code like this. I looked up MDN but there's no mention about toString having parameters. What does 3 do inside n.toString(3)?

```
function solution(n) {
  n = n.toString(3).split('').reverse().join('')
  return parseInt(n, 3)
}
```

Comment: You may have been looking at the wrong toString() method, have a look at [Number.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#syntax)

Comment: *"What does parameter in Array toString does?"* `n` probably isn't an array. Most likely it's meant to be a number, and as Nick points out, `number`'s `toString` does take an optional argument.

Comment: What made you think `n` is an array?

Answer (score 6):

This is [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString), not `Array.prototype.toString()`. It takes `radix` as an optional parameter.

> An integer in the range 2 through 36 specifying the base to use for representing numeric values.

Your code converts `n` to base-3. If you want to convert a number to binary, you'd do `n.toString(2)`

```js
const n = 16,
      bases = [2, 3, 4, 10, 16]

console.log(
  bases.map(radix => n.toString(radix))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an optional parameter when converting number to string:

> Optional. Which base to use for representing a numeric value. Must be
> an integer between 2 and 36. 2 - The number will show as a binary
> value 8 - The number will show as an octal value 16 - The number will
> show as an hexadecimal value

Answer (score 1):

This is the Radix (a number represent  base-3 numeral system or any other numeral systems). For example if you put 2 instead of 3 this function convert the result into the binary system.
you can put from 2 - 36 in it as the parameter.And the default value is 10 and this parameter is completely optional.

test this one:

```
var x = 10;
x.toString(2); // output: "1010"
```